# Solve multiple equations in one go

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following code:

```
a1 := 2
b1 := 1
a2 := 1
b2 := 1/2
x1 := 0
y1 := 1
x2 := 0
y2 := 4

cSol = Solve[
   a1 (a1^2 b2^2 m^2 + b1^2 (b2^2 - (c + m x1 - y1)^2)) == 
   b2 (a1^2 (a2^2 m^2 + b2^2) - a2^2 (c + m x2 - y2)^2), c];
cc = cSol[[All, 1, 2]];
FullSimplify[TableForm[Table[cc[[i]], {i, 1, 2}]]]
```

which gives the two values $-2$ and $2$ as output.

I then want to do the following equation solving

```
Solve[(a1^2 m (cc[[1]] - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 ==
      (a1^2 m^2 + b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + a1^2 (cc[[1]] - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2), m]
Solve[(a1^2 m (cc[[2]] - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 ==
      (a1^2 m^2 + b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + a1^2 (cc[[2]] - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2), m]
```

for both values of $c$, in one sweep go, and thereby giving me four values for $m$ as output.

How do I do that without having to solve the equation for both `c[[1]]` and `c[[2]]` one at the time, but instead do it in one sweep go?

P.S. I used more or less the same technique as when solving for $c$, before I delete my code by mistake, and now I can't figure out how to do it again. `:-(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you may use the solutions for $c$ in their original `Rule` form as this is more elegant than using parts:

```
Solve[
  (a1^2 m (c - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 == (a1^2 m^2 + b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + 
  a1^2 (c - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2), m
] /. cSol // Flatten
```

> {m -> -(Sqrt[35]/2), m -> Sqrt[35]/2, m -> -(Sqrt[3]/2), 
>    m -> Sqrt[3]/2}

But to do it in one sweep, why not simply do:

```
eq1 =  a1 (a1^2 b2^2 m^2 + b1^2 (b2^2 - (c + m x1 - y1)^2)) == 
       b2 (a1^2 (a2^2 m^2 + b2^2) - a2^2 (c + m x2 - y2)^2);
eq2 = (a1^2 m (c - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 == (a1^2 m^2 + b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + 
       a1^2 (c - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2);

sol = Solve[ eq1 && eq2, {m, c} ]
```

> {{m -> -(Sqrt[35]/2), c -> -2}, {m -> Sqrt[35]/2, 
>     c -> -2}, {m -> -(Sqrt[3]/2), c -> 2}, {m -> Sqrt[3]/2, c -> 2}}

To get the $m$ values you simply do:

```
m /. sol
```

> $\left\{-\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\}$

Comment: Awesome! (I'm a novice when it comes to using Mathematica.)

Answer (score 1):

"In one go": Subtract one side from the other, multiply the sides, set equal to zero, and solve:

```
Solve[0 == Times @@ ((a1^2 m (cc - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 == (a1^2 m^2 + 
         b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + a1^2 (cc - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2) /. 
     Equal -> Subtract),
 m]
(*  {{m -> -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {m -> Sqrt[3]/2}, {m -> -(Sqrt[35]/2)}, {m -> Sqrt[35]/2}}  *)
```

But it might be better to solve each and join the solutions:

```
Join @@ Table[
  Solve[(a1^2 m (ci - y1) - b1^2 x1)^2 == (a1^2 m^2 + 
       b1^2)*(b1^2 x1^2 + a1^2 (ci - y1)^2 - a1^2 b2^2), m],
  {ci, cc}]
(*  {{m -> -(Sqrt[35]/2)}, {m -> Sqrt[35]/2}, {m -> -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {m -> Sqrt[3]/2}}  *)
```